# SharePoint Approval Workflow-Different Approvers

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

In my limited experience of approval workflows on SP, as I understand it you have to define who the approval  individual(s) will be within the workflow itself. Whenever it is started it will automatically go to those individuals.

Is it possible to have it so that when a workflow is started the user instigating it can define who needs to approve and if applicable in what order (sequential or parallel)?

Using SP2013 and SP2013 workflows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! This will be through the workflow initiation form. In the form, you can define the workflow variable through SharePoint Designer, and use that variable in your workflow after the user starts the workflow. So if the user inputs "User A" to the workflow variable in the initiation form, that "User A" will be bound to the workflow variable.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-workflow-initiation-form-26879578-a62b-4fef-8b7e-9e4400afc94b

Answer (score 0):

You can add approver's as fields in the list. And once user creates the list item they can fill in the details.

Then in the workflow you can pull approver information from current item approver field.

https://amalhashim.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/sharepoint-custom-approval-workflow-with-dynamic-approvers-using-sharepoint-designer/